# Use title in fancybox to open up another link in a separate window

Tags: php, jquery

All,
I've got the following code to display a group of instagram photos and then I open them on my site with fancybox:

```
$output .= '<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>';

$output .= '<div id="bd-instagram">';

for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
    $output .= '<div class="bd-instagram-item">
    <a rel="instagram-widget" class="fancybox" title="This is a title" href="'.$images[$i]['image_large'].'">
    <img src="'.$images[$i]['image_small'].'" alt=""></a>
    </div>';
}
```

The fancybox opens up and displays the title "This is a title" underneath the image. However I'd actually like to make this a link so that when someone clicks on the title it opens up a link. I was trying to do something like this:

```
<a rel="instagram-widget" class="fancybox" title="<a href="http://www.instagram.com">Testing</a>" href="'.$images[$i]['image_large'].'">
```

That doesn't work though and produces some odd HTML on my page. Does anyone have any idea on how to do something like that this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try encoding the HTML in the title. For example, use `&lt;` for a < symbol. No idea whether this will work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: This is correct. I did something like this: &lt;a href=&quot;text.html&quot;&gt;hello&lt;/a&gt; This added the link for me and it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Fancybox has a titleFormat option, which you can set to a callback. I'm seeing this like:

```
function formatTitle(){
   return "<a href='http://instagram.com' target="_blank">test</a>";
}

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
'titleFormat' : formatTitle
});
```

I'm not sure I'm right, but the [documentation](http://fancybox.net/api) says:

*titleFormat - Callback to customize title area. You can set any html - custom image counter or even custom navigation*